# While Restoring the Binary log files to Amazon MySQL RDS from EC2 instance getting the following error."ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 8: Access denied"

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We are migrating 30GB size production database from Noah cloud server to Amazon MySQL RDS server.

To reduce the production downtime, we're trying to restore the full DB dump file in one day and binary log file on another day to up the database in Amazon MySQL RDS server.

We restored the full dump file through EC2 instance by moving the MySQL dump file. But when we try to restore the binary log file from Amazon EC2 instance, we're getting the following error:

> ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 8: Access denied; you need (at least
>   one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.

**Note: We did Google and changed the Amazon MySQL parameter `log_bin_trust_function_creators=1` and restarted the server**.

But we're still facing the above issue.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that RDS doesn't support using `mysqlbinlog` to playback a log file.

The first time you encounter a `BINLOG '...` statement in the output, you'll get the permission denied error because those events are interpreted in a fully-privileged context -- there is no privilege checking done when the events are processed, it's done up front -- by requiring that the user executing the `BINLOG '...` statement has the `SUPER` privilege -- which you don't get and can't have, with RDS, presumably because it would allow you to break things.

But, there's a workaround, which ultimately might be better, anyway.

After restoring the dump file, you can actually connect your RDS master to a MySQL Server outside of RDS, and temporarily make your master a slave of the external database.  It will connect, fetch the binlogs, and play them back like a normal slave, syncing its data to the external master in almost real time, until you shut down the external master and move your application to point to the RDS machine.

They introduced this capability specifically for the purpose of migrating a live external system into RDS with minimal downtime.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/migrate-mysql-data-to-amazon-rds-and-back/

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer Michael . However I can't do replication with existing MySQL server network.Since they have some restriction to do replication to connect the MySQL server. Is there any possibilities to execute the mysqlbinlog files in RDS?

Comment: If you can get the binary logs from a server, then you should be able to replicate from that server.  It doesn't make sense that you have enough privilege to get one but not the other.

Comment: Hi Michael, I mean I can take the MySQL binlog files from the existing server entering with in the network and can move the files from there. However we cant access the MySQL server and the port 3306 over the another network.

Comment: If you can SSH to that machine, then, yes, you probably can connect to 3306 from outside... with an SSH tunnel.  RDS doesn't support this directly, but it is straightforward enough with another machine in the middle, either at your data center or in EC2, which you'd configure as the master from RDS's perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I had met the same issue, I changed the DEFINER id ( mention the id you use to restore ) in dumped sql file ( /*!50013 DEFINER=`RESTOREID`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */

Then it started working!